# how to enable focus in the main frame, when a new window was opened

Tags: c#

C#
how to enable focus in the main frame, when a new window was opened and there is no way to activate actions in the main frame.
Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like you are using OpenDialog instead of Open when opening the form.  You need to provide more details as to what you are doing though for people to be able to help you better.  Particularly if you are using WinForms or WPF

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the new window from within the main window, then you can make your new window [modeless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28VS.71%29.aspx) and set this.[`Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) to set focus.

From MSDN:

> ... A modal form or dialog box must be closed or hidden before you can continue working with the rest of the application
>
> Modeless forms let you shift the focus between the form and another form without having to close the initial form. The user can continue to work elsewhere in any application while the form is displayed.

Comment: I open process windows from within the main window,  I want to be focus also from the main fram